# Disable device back button on SOME page [jquery mobile / android]

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, mobile

I need some approach advice on how to handle this. I had multi-pages app, Login page, Register page, After Logged In Page and on...

Now I found out, after user logged in, I check the login into and programmatically redirect the user to the After Logged In Main Page.

The problem start here, on Android, the user can use the device back button to return to the Login Page which is not logical.

The question, how I can prevent Device Back button ONLY on the "After Logged in Page" to avoid user go back to Login Page. Other back I would like to allow user to user device back button to navigate.

In other words, I need to disable Device Back button on some page, not all page. Please advice, thank you.

Lesz

Comment: you cant disable it, but you can prevent user from navigating back. You need to listen to [`navigate`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040158/disable-jquery-mobile-transition-when-going-back-in-ios7-safari-history/23040309?noredirect=1#comment35213576_23040309) and prevent user on [`pagebeforechange`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/#pagebeforechange).

Answer (score -1):

You can put this in your Activity to disable the back button completely.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your info. I'm very new to javascript/jquery. Do you mind give me some example on how to use your example code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nyx This doest work for jquery the answer is invalid, its for native android code