# Slider just working on First Page (jQM), but Failed on Page Two, Three and on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

*Hello everyone*, I have problem with Swiper on JQM multipage document.

I'm using Swiper by http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/ in my JQM project.

I can have the slide display and working fine on my First Page of my Multipage JQM document structure. But when ever I try to put the slider to other JQM page other than the First Page, the slides 'Will Load and Display' BUT 'Not Working correctly'.

***Description of Not Working Correctly:*** The loading error will cause incorrect width of the whole slider, the content/list not completely loaded and swipe gesture not working correctly, as it should stop at each slide when swipe/drag left-right.

Please help, thank you.

The following two example, first I load the Swiper on First Page of JQM document and its working as it should:

**Here is the JSfiddle for Working Slider [Page One]**: http://jsfiddle.net/h73k2/11/

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.3dflow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/appstore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">
</head>
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
                <div class="swiper-container featured">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/1.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/2.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/3.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/4.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/5.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/6.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/7.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/1.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/2.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/3.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/4.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/5.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/6.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/7.jpg)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#page2">Page Two</a></p>  
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
        <p><a href="#page1">Back to Page One</a></p>    
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

    <!-- content goes here-->


<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Don't forget to get the latest Swiper and scrollbar version here-->
<script src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/appstore.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***JSfiddle for Not-Working Slider [Page Two]:*** http://jsfiddle.net/jgYGJ/8/

**Not working on the following page** after moved the Swiper DIV to Page Two:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.3dflow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/appstore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">
</head>
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#page2">Page Two</a></p>  
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
                <div class="swiper-container featured">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/1.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/2.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/3.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/4.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/5.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/6.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/7.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/1.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/2.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/3.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/4.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/5.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/6.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(img/big/7.jpg)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
        <p><a href="#page1">Back to Page One</a></p>    
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

    <!-- content goes here-->


<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Don't forget to get the latest Swiper and scrollbar version here-->
<script src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/appstore.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS to initiate swiper:**

```
$(function(){
    //Featured Slide
    var featuredSwiper = $('.featured').swiper({
        slidesPerView:'auto',
        centeredSlides: true,
        initialSlide:7,
        tdFlow: {
            rotate : 30,
            stretch :10,
            depth: 150
        }
    })

    //Thumbs
    $('.thumbs-cotnainer').each(function(){
        $(this).swiper({
            slidesPerView:'auto',
            offsetPxBefore:25,
            offsetPxAfter:10,
            calculateHeight: true
        })
    })

    //Banners
    $('.banners-container').each(function(){
        $(this).swiper({
            slidesPerView:'auto',
            offsetPxBefore:25,
            offsetPxAfter:10
        })  
    })
})
```

**Code update:**

[image: Screenshot of the slider]

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Don't forget to get the latest Swiper and scrollbar version here-->
    <script src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src="js/appstore.js"></script>-->
    <script>
            $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforehide", function (e, ui) {
            var activeP = ui.nextPage;
            var activeID = ui.nextPage[0].id;
            if (activeID == "page2" && $(".swiper-container", activeP).length === 0) {
                $("body .swiper-container")
                    .removeClass("swiper-hidden")
                    .prependTo($(".ui-content", activeP));
            }
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.3dflow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/appstore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">
</head>
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page One</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
        <p>View Slider on <a href="#page2">Page Two</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Two</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>
        <p><a href="#page1">Back to Page One</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
<!-- content goes here-->
<div class="swiper-container featured swiper-hidden">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/1.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/2.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/3.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/4.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/5.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/6.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/7.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/1.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/2.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/3.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/4.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/5.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/6.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://furkidtag.com/img/big/7.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you going to use the same swiper on all pages?

Comment: Hi @Omar, now I didn't plan to use on same page. Its currently on different page. I hope to fix this one to understand what have I done wrong. Then later I can study method to use multiple slider on same page.

Comment: The problem is swiper auto initialize itself, so you can't control when to intialize it. I can fix this by preloading it outside any page and then copy it to target page once initialized. I'll get you with a demo later b

Comment: Thanks. Awaiting for your update.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DL2cq/ check this, swiper is preloaded and then appended into target page.

Comment: Hi @Omar, I copy your code from jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DL2cq) into test file local server. The code I have put it into my original post at "Code Update" (bottom of the initial post). The slider seems like not being initialize. Can advice what is wrong?

Comment: check code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5JxAL/), it should work. I've replaced `pagecontainerbeforehide` with `pagecontainerhide` and I added `.swiper()` function to initialize swiper.

Comment: Hi Omar, its working now. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi @Omar, do I have to put this js code into the head of the document? I load all my JS files (external/internal) at the bottom of the document. So can I place this js code to the bottom after all js files  loaded?

Comment: If the page is external, load code inside page div, if the page is internal place code in head.

Comment: I'm working on preloaded slider, I'll post an update soon.

Comment: @Omar, Thanks will wait for your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize "swiper" on `pagecontainershow` event. This event cant be bound to a specific page, so you need to retrieve *active Page*'s id and compare it with id of the page containing "swiper".

Place the below code in `head` and don't wrap it in `$(function () {});`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").find('.featured').swiper({
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        centeredSlides: true,
        initialSlide: 7,
        tdFlow: {
            rotate: 30,
            stretch: 10,
            depth: 150
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SfDTH/)**

To retrieve *active page*'s id

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  /* page's object */
  var active = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
  /* page's id */
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
  if( activePage == "targetPageID") {
    $(".featured", active).swiper({
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        centeredSlides: true,
        initialSlide: 7,
        tdFlow: {
            rotate: 30,
            stretch: 10,
            depth: 150
        }
    });
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JT9Qc/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the demo. I found something. If you click back to page one, then back to two and then back to one. You the see the image is getting darker and darker, like the style duplicating.

Comment: @user3053891 true, it looks like widget is being initialized whenever page is shown. This can be fixed.

Comment: Hi @Omar, does this happen to you? When ever I refresh the page and First click on the Page Link, the slider will be shown without style for a split second then only change to slider with style. Does it happen to you?

Comment: @user3053891 yes, this is normal, because you initialize swiper when page is fully shown. If you want to avoid this, you'll need to preload it and then copy it as in the first demo.

Comment: Do you mind give me example on how to preload and copy? Sorry really new to JS. I'm very surprise such a common requirement need to many different steps just to display a slider out of the first page. Does this mean building multiple html document structure is better than single file multiple page?

Comment: @user3053891 this a preloading demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DL2cq/ place code in the demo inside HEAD tag. Each model has its' own pros and cons. _Multi-Page Model_ like the on you're using, requires a bit of code to get plugins working properly.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Please do vote my question up if it's worth it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Omar, Now I'm using the most updated code you're giving me. I realise one down side, the slider, yes now the style is applied before show the slider. But, it show the Page first then only the slider show up suddenly by pushing all other content down. Is there any way to make the slider load and show together with the page content instead of separately. Please advice, thank you.

Now I'm using this jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5JxAL/

In this example, the slider is show up differently with Page content too.

Comment: Hi @Omar, I found one problem with the slide. If I put the slide in a Page after login, then when I logout and Login again. The slide will be missing after login. The container height/width is still there. But just empty with no slide loaded. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @user3053891 hi, can you post a new question with more details? :)

Comment: Hi @Omar, really should open up a new question? Cause this problem is still at the first issue. The initialisation of the slider still not working as expected as I describe the problem above. On iPhone doesn't show at all after logout and login. On Android, after logout and login, the slide will be broken exactly like the first error I encounter on this first post.

Comment: @user3053891 is login page a separate HTML file?

Comment: Nope. It's all under one single HTML document. Login is by checking respond from server JSON. So login page and the slider page are in the same HTML under different JQM page.

Comment: Hi Omar, do you have any solution for this problem? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086380/disable-device-back-button-on-some-page-jquery-mobile-android/22086708?noredirect=1#comment35223947_22086708