# Disable jQuery Mobile transition when going back in iOS7 Safari history

Tags: jquery-mobile

As described [here](http://getpocket.com/a/read/440771301) in Safari on iOS7 - if you swipe in from the left of the screen it triggers a history back event as if the user clicked the back button.

The default behavior of jQuery Mobile is to reverse the transition that was used to reach a particular page when going back to the previous page. This works great when using the `<` and `>` buttons but looks terrible when swiping in from the left.

Is there a way to completely disable transitions in the 'reverse' direction using jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the `pagecontainerbeforetransition` event on the page widget.

You can then look at `ui.options.reverse` and cancel the transition. If you want you can detect iOS7, but I think I'll just give this to all my visitors.

```
    $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function (event, ui)
    {
        if (ui.options.reverse == true)
        {
            ui.options.transition = "none";
        }
    });
```

---

Here's a sample of a typical `ui.options` object.

```
{"reverse":true,"changeHash":false,"fromHashChange":true,"showLoadMsg":true,
 "allowSamePageTransition":false,"transition":"none"}
```

For some reason `reverse` always seems to be true even when navigating forward. May be a but, but I decided to check for it anyway.

---

Comment: listen to `navigate` event, if direction is `back`, set `ui.options.transitiion` to `none`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7Gy3S/

Comment: You should post this as another Answer

Comment: It's only an update on your answer. Feel free to add it to yours :) edit: btw, if you press browsers back button or have a link with `data-rel=back`, the direction will be `back`.

Comment: I've update the demo to reflect my previous comment. pls go ahead and add it to your answer.